# Forms Web Browser control won't proceed or redirect on it's own

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I have a main form that opens a new form that contains a web browser control that navigates to the entered url when it is loaded.  I've tried different things I've found and this is my latest code:  I have a function (GoToURL) that is triggered at the Shown event of the form which is here:

```
public delegate void Launch();

private void launchBrowser()
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(GlobalData.URL);
}

private void GoToURL(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Invoke(new Launch(launchBrowser));
}
```

I have nothing in the Document Completed function:

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

The web browser control loads the url just fine and I can scroll around in it, but on some links or buttons the control goes white and nothing happens.  It won't proceed with the desired function.  A more specific example is I am logging into a site and once I click the submit button it just hangs there.  A "loading" image is presented and it just sits there.  I know the Document Completed function above is triggered when this happens, too.

I apologize for my inexperience with C# and this is the first time using the web browser control (forms not wpf), so I am at a loss of what to try.  I suspect its a threading issue, but that's as far as I got.

Comment: You mean to say you won't see a progress ring running?change your IE emulation I think it defaults to IE7 make it IE11

Comment: I currently have IE10 and have the same problem when I manually try to use the same url.  I'm trying now to upgrade and see how that works.  Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade is alright but you also need to set your browser emulation version

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is this IE emulation for the webbrowser control itself?  I don't see anything that would let me do anything like that.

Comment: I switched to the geckofx webbrowser control and it works great.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing issues within the browser itself. Please launch IE and test the same there. I suspect you'll see the same issues.

Your experience is tied to the version of Internet Explorer you have in your system, and javascript errors have been frequents in the earlier versions of IE. Upgrade to IE11 in any case.

If that's not an option, try using a browser control with a different rendering engine. I'm too lazy to find and list the options, but I've used a few and they work well.

Comment: You're right.  I never use IE and the site I'm using has been fine with Chrome and Firefox.  I have IE10 on my Windows Server 2012 system and it just hangs at the same spot.  I'm surprised at myself for not even trying that first.  I'm going to see if I can upgrade IE or use a different control.

Comment: I decided to try Geckofx and their webbrowser control and it works great.  Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid JavaScript Errors please follow this

```
public frmMain()
{
 //Java Script Error popup block
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
}
```

Please Check this on loading Uri using

```
 webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(Url.Trim().ToString());
```

Url - your desired Url

Comment: Trimming the url is a good idea.  Thanks!  I didn't have that in place.